# Display custom text instead of "Error! Reference source not found" in word cross-reference field when reference is broken

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a cross-reference field in my Word document

```
{ REF bookmark_A \h }
```

I want to display my custom text, say `Default Bookmark A Title`, instead of bold **`Error! Reference source not found`** when bookmark_A will be improperly broken in future.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That's Word's internal error system. You'll have to dig deep to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Simply wrap the field in an IF field like this:

```
{ IF { REF bookmark_A \h} = "Error! Reference source not found" "My custom error message" "{ REF bookmark_A \h} }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work :( I tried `{ IF { REF bookmark_A \h} = "Error! Reference source not found" "My custom error message" "Bookmark Present" }`, and it prints just `REF` regardless bookmark present or not.

Comment: It seems that condition `{ REF bookmark_A \h} = "Error! Reference source not found"` is not valid. (I use Word 2003)

Comment: @Sergant, it works for me on Microsoft Word 2007 (sorry I don't have 2003 to test with). Two things: the error message needs to end in a full stop. The older version of MS Word might require speech marks around the REF field in the conditional (the first part).

Lastly I have prepared a template that works on my side, have a look at it and see how it goes: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4h-y94oB7DOM2lLYy0wSVVsTDA